# Handle exception and continue executing

Tags: php, exception, callback

[EDIT - Disclaimer: This is a really bad idea, see the accepted answer for an actual solution.]

I define my own exception handler using set_exception_handler() function. After the handler execution, I need the script to continue. Is there any way to do it?

Disclaimer: I know try-catch blocks but I need to process Exceptions dynamicaly. Every calling of Clazz::foo() specifies its own exceptions which should be caught by my handler. That's the reason I can't use it.

Example:

```
class Clazz {

    private static $exceptions;

    public static function foo(array $exceptions) {
        set_exception_handler(array(__CLASS__, "exception_handler"));
        self::$exceptions = $exceptions;
        throw new RandomException;
        echo "I need this to be printed!";
    }

    public static function exception_handler($exception) {
        // process the exception in my way...
        // if $exception in self::$exceptions than 1, else 2, fi
        restore_exception_handler();
        // continue in some way, like it has never happenned
    }

}
```

Comment: i dont get it, could you please specify your needs?

Comment: This looks you don't understand exceptions at all. This is just bad idea...

Comment: You ***could*** set up an event mediator object, inject it into a custom exception handler class, register a callable of the custom exception handler class with `set_exception_handler` and have a whole chain of listeners that listen for an uncaught exception event. Though I'm not sure how good an idea this would really be ...

Comment: The reason you're struggling is that this is not how exceptions work, because this is not what exceptions _mean_. Stop trying to use them in this manner. Just call some function instead.

Comment: I'd love to handle it without exceptions. However, foo() function is supposed to launch custom code (from libraries) which throws exceptions and I can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just bad idea. I just hope you don't understand how [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) work and you're not meaning the question.

First of all, setting exception handler... [Exception handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) is called when the exceptions is propagated to main script (actually out of it) and your script is therefore done:

> Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught within a try/catch block. **Execution will stop** after the exception_handler is called.

You should either use what's [Xeoncross suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574616/1149736), but I think you have problem with called function/method that is throwing exceptions so you can do this:

```
class Clazz {

    private static $exceptions;

    public static function foo(array $exceptions) {
        set_exception_handler(array(__CLASS__, "exception_handler"));
        self::$exceptions = $exceptions;
        try {
            throw new RandomException;
        } catch( Exception $e){
            self::exception_handler( $exception);
        }
        echo "I need this to be printed!";
    }

    public static function exception_handler(Exception $exception) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is much simplier, I had just another silly idea... This solves my problem since I can catch ALL exceptions and then throw some of them again if I need.

Comment: @PavelS. The problem with exception handler is... When should it act? When function finishes? When parent function finishes? When main script finishes? It believe that relying on exception handler is just bad practice... Anyway if you want it with less code, you may do this: 1) prefix all your method names with `_`, 2) implement method [`__call($name,$args)`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) with: `if(strncmp( $name, '_', 1) == 0){throw new Exception( 'Nested!');} try { return call_user_func_array( array($this, '_' . $name), $args);}catch(){} return null;`

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like this in you startup file

```
/**
 * Set the default exception handler.
 *
 * @param Exception $exception The exception to handle
 */
$handler = function(Exception $exception)
{
    //print $exception;
};

set_exception_handler($handler);

/**
 * Register the PHP error handler. All PHP errors will fall into this
 * handler, which will convert the error into an ErrorException object
 * and pass the exception into the common exception handler.
 *
 * After all, there should never be any errors in our application. If
 * there are then we need to know about them and fix them - not ignore
 * them.
 *
 * Notice, this function will ignore the error if it is less than the
 * current error reporting level.
 */
set_error_handler(function($code, $error, $file, $line) use ($handler)
{
    if((error_reporting() & $code) === 0) return TRUE;

    $handler(new ErrorException($error, $code, 0, $file, $line));
});

/**
 * Register the PHP shutdown handler. This function will be called
 * at the end of the PHP script or on a fatal PHP error. If an error
 * has occured, we will convert it to an ErrorException and pass it
 * to the common exception handler for the framework.
 */
register_shutdown_function(function() use ($handler)
{
    if($error = error_get_last())
    {
        extract($error, EXTR_SKIP);
        $handler(new ErrorException($message, $type, 0, $file, $line));
    }
});


/**
 * Setting the PHP error reporting level to -1 essentially forces PHP to
 * report every error, and is guranteed to show every error on future
 * versions of PHP. This will insure that our handlers above are
 * notified about everything.
 */
error_reporting(-1);

/**
 * At the same time we want to disable PHP's default error display since
 * we are now using our own.
 */
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. *Fortunately* there is no way to do that

Comment: 'Fortunately' ? Say that again when you have to use a 3rd party library in which exceptions are thrown. Even if you have a fully fledged, huge application which can handle ANY issue that the 3rd party library encounters, your entire application will still come to a grinding halt.

Comment: @unity100: yes, fortunately. I don't have any issues with that. (including **huge** applications). I prefer my code to work correctly, rather than throwing exceptions but continuing executing with *broken data* (that's what you probably prefer)

Comment: Yes, you prefer YOUR code to work correctly. Now shove in google's php client library to your application to do something. And then you will see how irritating exceptions are. Their code throws exceptions when ANY error is returned from google - causing your code to die out even though you can just try to send your user to another login, hell, even attempt reauthorization with google. BAD.

Comment: @unity100: "Their code throws exceptions when ANY error is returned from google" --- and that's what I actually expect. If some error happened - I don't want the error to spread, I want the library to throw exception and give my code the ability to handle it.

Comment: what does an error 'spreading' even mean ? when their library throws its exception, your entire application just dies in your face. they dont give your code the ability to handle it - execution stops right there, with an ugly exception message in your (or user's) face. all you can do is to create a general exception handling function and beautify the message, or modify the shutdown handler function to redirect them elsewhere. thats as much as you can do.

Comment: "they dont give your code the ability to handle it - execution stops right there, with an ugly exception message" --- it's not an exception then. Exception always may be handled by caller.

Comment: They are uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @unity100: so why don't you catch it you in your caller code?

Comment: The problem is not catching the exception. The problem is that it stops execution of entire application. A case in point is, a user unauthorizing the application despite having a standing session and token for the google service. When that happens, google php client api throws an exception, which also includes a 401 code. If it was not an exception, you would json decode the response, get the 401 code, see that the app is unauthorized now, generate auth url and rerequest authorization, right ? Right. But when entire script dies with the exception, you cant do that.

Comment: @unity100: "When that happens, google php client api throws an exception, which also includes a 401 code" --- now you see, you're saying the issue isn't caused by exception, but that the php client adds something else to the response. And it's irrelevant to the exceptions right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19449/discussion-between-zerkms-and-unity100)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is a bad idea because code throwing an exception is expecting that any following code is not executed, and I guess that's the reason why it is not implemented in php.

But maybe that may help doing what you are trying to do:

```
function try_throw($exception) {
    if (!Clazz::exception_handler($exception))
        throw($exception);

}

class Clazz {

    private static $exceptions;

    public static function foo(array $exceptions) {
        set_exception_handler(array(__CLASS__, "exception_handler"));
        self::$exceptions = $exceptions;
        try_throw(new RandomException);
        echo "I need this to be printed!";
    }

    public static function exception_handler($exception) {
        // process the exception in my way...
        // if $exception in self::$exceptions than 1, else 2, fi
        return true;
        // continue in some way, like it has never happenned
        // to instead throw the exception the normal way
        return false;
    }

}
```